# how to place the watermark text diagonally in fpdf?

Tags: rotation, watermark

need to place the watermark text in imported pdf using fpdf

```
  for($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++){ 
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica','','25');
            $pdf->SetTextColor(200,200,200);
        
            $tplId = $pdf->importPage($i);
            $pdf->useTemplate($tplId, null, null, null, 210, true);
            $pdf->SetXY(30,120);
            $pdf->Write(0.5,$schoolname);
        }
```

unable to use rotate() function in above code? how to place the watermark text diagonally in pdf?